# NodeJS - Can not access file system before user login

Tags: node.js, centos, fs, pm2, listdir

I have a node server application that runs as service with pm2 on CentOS.
It must list all external drives with nodejs **fs** module. When root user is logged in, it works perfectly. with restarting OS, pm2 runs server again but there is no access to view directories.

here is my code to list all directories:

```
const driveList = require('drivelist');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const emptyDir = require('empty-dir');

const config = require('../config.json');


exports.list_all_drives = function(req, res) {
    return driveList.list((err, drives) => {

        if(err) return res.status(500).send('there was an error');

        let isWin = /^win/.test(process.platform);

        let usbDrives = [];
        drives.map((drive) => {
            if(isWin){
                for(let index in drive.mountpoints){
                    usbDrives.push(drive.mountpoints[index].path);
                }
            }else{
                if(!drive.system){
                    for(let index in drive.mountpoints){
                        usbDrives.push(drive.mountpoints[index].path);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        if(err) return res.status(500).send('there was an error');
        let records = [];
        usbDrives.forEach((name, i) => {
            let record = {};
            record.id = i;
            record.title = name;
            record.path = name;
            record.isDirectory = true;

            let skip = false;
            config.skipPath.forEach((val) => {
                if(record.path == val){
                    skip = true;
                }
            });

            if(!skip){
                records.push(record);
            }
        });
        res.status(200).send(records);
    });
};
```

When user is logged in, function works and list all OS directories but when system reboots it returns 500 error:

> {"errno":-2,"code":"ENOENT","syscall":"open","path":"/run/user/0/drivelist-ecc75a4a9523.sh"}

Comment: Does the user that runs the script on startup have permissions to that path?

Comment: How can I check this permission? what is this user's username?

Comment: How did you implement running the script on startup? Did you put it into a startup service? or did you run `pm2 startup` to enable it?

Comment: Yes, it is a startup service, I used **Pm2 startup -u root**

Comment: Ok so `-u root` will set the startup script so it runs as `root`. You can replicate the issue by running `sudo su` to get into root and then manually run the script to see if you can reproduce the issue.